# Am I using beta or stable?

Tags: upgrade

I have been doing so many `sudo apt-get update/(dist-)upgrade` since yesterday and  *something* happend - so that I am confused now whether I am using still beta or the stable version.

How do I figure that out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Open a terminal(type "gnome-terminal" on the dash) and type `lsb_release -a` and if the output is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

you are running the stable release and if the output is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```

(see the `development branch`) you are running the beta version.

Comment: `lsb_release -d` is enough

Comment: @Ask: Yes, even that would do.

Comment: @jobin Which package determines it's beta or stable release. I installed beta, now fully upgraded using synaptic, but still showing development branch ? How do I convert beta to stable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with command

```
update-manager -d
```

and find out if you see an Upgrade button.

Or using GUI run Sysinfo (available in the Ubuntu Software Center) and check out the System tab and read the text under Ubuntu.

If there shows Release 14.04  then you are out of beta.

---

**Update to @Jobin answer:**

you can just do it with :

```
lsb_release -d
```

This will show you the description only