# How do I check if I have the beta or stable version of Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I installed the Kubuntu 16.04 beta 2 and I plan to upgrade to the final release when it's out. I just want to know now how to check so I can make sure.

The solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449533/am-i-using-beta-or-stable) tells me that I have the stable version, even though I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the release announcement is made, check that all your packages are up to date, *e.g.*, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` should say

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If it does, you are on "the final release" (*i.e.*, you have the same set of packages as someone who downloaded the release ISO and installed from it).

Comment: So I wouldn't need to download it again? And will I get anything extra if I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your version by simply putting this command in terminal:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

LTS - means long term support

Here is more information about releases:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, as `/etc/issue` only says `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` even though it is not officially released yet.